# Is it reasonable to leave full time job and do freelancing instead?

Tags: contracts, attracting-clients, project-management, outsourcing, growth

I have been doing part time freelancing for that last 3 years. I generally work 2-4 hours daily as freelancer. I have another full time job in professional company.

Now some time I feel that I should leave full time job and should concentrate full time on freelancing because I am getting more money than my full time job salary by part time freelancing. Also I achieved TOP RATED FREELANCER badge in freelancing site. I also always having interest in freelancing, learn something new, work with different clients etc.I never get bored or tired when do work for clients. So should I take decision to leave full time job?

Comment: Related if not a duplicate: http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/913/how-to-make-the-jump-from-normal-employee-to-higher-level-freelancing/2461#2461 In short, length of time freelancing on the side or some rating on some site mean nothing. You have to look at your **financial** status and other life factors.

Comment: I don't see your situation as problematic. Why should you keep your full time job ?

Comment: @HarryCover - I agree with you but there is something like fear in mind as  this is risk in life so.. :)

Comment: If your public relation is good. And you are getting new customers day to day or weekly then must go for freelancing **Either way do freelancing with work** I followed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the money you're making from your **current** clients will support you financially, and you're confident that they'll continue to consistently provide you with work, then it's reasonable to quit your day job.

If your freelance business simply cannot grow because you have absolutely no time left during to day to take on more freelance work, and you're confident that you'll be able to attract substantial new business after freeing yourself from your day job, then it's reasonable to quit your day job.

If you're fully aware of and comfortable with the worst case scenario, then is it **reasonable** to quit your job. I'm not sure where in the world you are, so it may be simply looking at the financials. But if your full time job provides any sort of social benefits, that's something to consider too. (Paid family leave, health/medical, life insurance, retirement matching etc.)

All that being said

> "The reasonable man adapts himself to the conditions that surround him... The unreasonable man adapts surrounding conditions to himself... All progress depends on the unreasonable man."  ~George Bernard Shaw

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely should go freelance! It sounds like you have been successful as a part-time freelancer, and have tested out whether you would like it or not. If you currently have 1 or 2 clients that are consistently giving you work, I would say go for it.

Comment: Thank you for answer.. you have increased my confidence level.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your full-time job is. Can you support yourself with just freelancing? Freelancing is an up and down business, what happens when there is a dead week or two? I have been freelancing for a couple of months and have only gotten about 10 jobs. I created a website of my own, business facebook page and paid for advertising. I specialize in resume writing and actually contacted every college and university in my state and did get a little feedback. It's only been a couple of days but I did get some positive feedback. I have to freelance now because I am medically disabled but I would not do it unless you SPECIFICALLY work for a freelance company that will always supply work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really tough call. I was a freelancer for a long time on the side and it was really hard for me to make the jump to full-time because I am really risk adverse. Every year I would look at my taxes and see all the consulting revenue that I had made and then think "well that is great but it isn't a sure thing". I kept looking at that number rise year over year and I mean at some point you have to say to yourself that if it keeps going up, it will probably keep going up if you keep doing what you are doing. Now I am off on my own project and I really like being in startup mode and the freedom to work the hours I want. I mean I think at the end of the day you are working more but you are working for yourself and you get to set your own hours so it feels less like "work".

Comment: You are right. It is touch in start level but there will be many benefits and projects if we do things in right direction , right?